# HPLIP Toolbox crashes on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: crash, hplip, 23.04

I am using the HPLIP installed from repository, since the one from HPLIP download usually does not install, due to dependencies issues.

When I open the HPLIP Toolbox I get crash with main cause at /usr/share/hplip/toolbox.py.
If I run this Phython I get:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.22.10)
HP Device Manager ver. 15.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/toolbox.py", line 280, in <module>
    toolbox = ui.DevMgr5(__version__, device_uri,  None)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py", line 238, in __init__
    core =  CoreInstall(MODE_CHECK)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.passwordObj = password.Password(ui_mode)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.__readAuthType()  # self.__authType
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 119, in __readAuthType
    distro_name = get_distro_std_name(os_name)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'get_distro_std_name' is not defined. Did you mean: 'get_distro_name'?
```

The solution I implemented was to edit file /usr/share/hplip/base/password.py and replace get_distro_std_name() by the get_distro_name(), used on previous Ubuntu, 22.10.

```
Line 119:
From
        distro_name = get_distro_std_name(os_name)

To
        distro_name = get_distro_name().lower().replace(" ","")


Line 323
From
        distro_name = get_distro_std_name(os_name)

To
        distro_name = get_distro_name().lower()
```

How can this be reported to team in charge of HPLIP code in Ubuntu?

Regards

Comment: If it's https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/hplip you mean, refer to the top right and click on *bug reports* and you'll get a new page of bugs, where you can check to see if its already reported, or click the *report a bug* top right to start a new bug report. Rather than start it online, I'd suggest using `ubuntu-bug hplip` on your terminal though. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  (*Include your suggested fix in the bug report*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Thanks guiverc.
This answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I implemented was to edit file /usr/share/hplip/base/password.py and replace get_distro_std_name() by the get_distro_name(), used on previous Ubuntu, 22.10.

Line 119:
From
distro_name = get_distro_std_name(os_name)

To
distro_name = get_distro_name().lower().replace(" ","")

And Line 323
From
distro_name = get_distro_std_name(os_name)

To
distro_name = get_distro_name().lower()

Comment: Confirmed it works on my Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop. My device is HP Laserjet Tank MFP 2606sdw.

Answer (score -1):

Followed the advice from Fernando Sprocati and now my HPLIP Toolbox launches. This was on a completely clean installation of 23.04.